# Find a basis of a subspace defined by a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ be a basis of $V$.

Let $$V \supset S= \left \{v:v=\sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \alpha_iv_i,   \alpha_1+2\alpha_2+\alpha_3-\alpha_4=0 \right \}$$

Find a basis of $S$.

I don't understand how to solve this, usually in these kind of problems I'm given the vectors $v_i$, could you guys give me some tips?

I'm sorry I'm not posting any of my work, but this really confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $v\in S$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
v &= \alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+(\alpha_1+2\,\alpha_2+\alpha_3)v_4 \\
&= \alpha_1(v_1+v_4)+\alpha_2(v_2+2\,v_4)+\alpha_3(v_3+v_4)
\end{align*}
This proves that $\beta=\{v_1+v_4,v_2+2\,v_4,v_3+v_4\}$ spans $S$. To see that $\beta$ is linearly independent, suppose that
$$
\alpha_1(v_1+v_4)+\alpha_2(v_2+2\,v_4)+\alpha_3(v_3+v_4)=\vec 0
$$
Then 
$$
\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+(\alpha_1+2\,\alpha_2+\alpha_3)v_4=\vec 0\tag{1}
$$
Since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a basis for $V$, (1) implies that
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1&=0&\alpha_2&=0&\alpha_3&=0&\alpha_1+2\,\alpha_2+\alpha_3&=0
\end{align*}
Thus $\beta$ is linearly independent. Hence $\beta$ is a basis for $S$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:$v = \alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3+(\alpha_1+2\alpha_2+\alpha_3)v_4=\alpha_1(v_1+v_4)+\alpha_2(v_2+2v_4)++\alpha_3(v_3+v_4)$. From this you can see the basis. In fact, the basis is: $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1+v_4,v_2+2v_4,v_3+v_4\}$. Can you prove it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space of vectors such that the coefficients in the given basis of $V$ satisfy one linear equation. Since there are 4 coefficients satisfying one nontrivial linear equation, your basis should consist of three elements which come from "row reducing" the "augmented matrix"

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

There's not much to be done in this particular case since there's only one equation, and so the matrix is already in reduced row echelon form. So you can now read off that $\alpha_1=-2\alpha_2-\alpha_3+\alpha_4$ and $\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$ are all free variables. So you can get a basis for $S$ by choosing appropriate values for $\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$; the easiest choice is to make each one of them $1$ while the others are zero.

Note that this question is basically just an abstract version of the question "find a basis for $S \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ satisfying $x_1+2x_2+x_3-x_4=0$".